# XCode file paths point to nonexistent directories

Tags: ios, xcode

Right now I'm running XCode 3.2.6. I'm working off of someone else's code, and when I open the project it around 150 files have the wrong path (even when set to "relative to enclosing group."

Instead of using /appname/folder the point to /../../Documents/appname/folder.

I'm aware that some other people have had similar issues with XCode 3.2 in the past, which is why I'm upgrading to Lion now so I can use 4.0. However, has anyone found a fix for this in 3.2?

Also, I was wondering if there was a file that held all of the paths so  I could run a script through it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will notice that the `.xcodeproj` file itself is actually a Bundle (a.k.a. a directory).  If you cd to this directory in Terminal, you can use grep to figure out which files contain the paths using `grep -r -i "path here"`.  These files are formatted in XML and some other similar format, so it should be pretty easy to use `sed` or something to fix some of the paths.  And of course, I **ALWAYS** suggest backing up any files before you autonomously replace stuff in them.